# Ignoring large files in IntelliJ file search

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have a large file (9mb) in our SVN project structure. Whenever I Ctrl-Shift-F (find-in-files) in IntelliJ and search, I get the popup "large file encountered" asking me if I want to search within this file.

Is there a way to permanently disable this popup, either globally or for this specific file?

Comment: This is actually not a programming problem, but a software problem. Technically this belongs on superuser.com, not here. But OK, I don't have problems with that. It's just a dev tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been [addressed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEADEV-3947) in IDEA 9.0, you can [try the beta](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

> Ignored files (if any) now reported in lightweight baloon notification after the search is finished. No way to force scanning though.

Comment: Thanks, I might try it. Is it compatible, regarding the proj and iml file structure?

Comment: As usual, IDEA project files are not backwards compatible, it means that IDEA will automatically convert older project files into the new format and create a backup of your old files. You should not open new project files in the old IDE versions, use the files from the backup instead.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have intellij v14 and I can see the notification. is it possible to enable these files to become part of the listed occurrences in the main find panel??